# c# Polymorphism. Cast from base class to derivate

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a question about this little piece of code in C# (assume the function ManageCars is in the MainProgram).
The code should work, but my question is that: is this a right way to use Polymorphism ? Is it correct to cast from Car to Ferrari or is it a bad programming way? The only problem I found is that I need a very long switch/case in order to manage all the types (Ferrari, Mercedes...).
What is you opinion?

```
class Car
{
    string _plate = "";

    public string Plate
    {
        get { return _plate; }
        set { _plate = value; }
    }

}
class Ferrari : Car
{
    string specialName = "";

    public string SpecialName
    {
        get { return specialName; }
        set { specialName = value; }
    }

    Ferrari (Car obj )
    {
        specialName = (obj is Ferrari) ? ((Ferrari)obj).SpecialName : "";
    }
}

static void ManageCars (Car A)
{
    if (A is Ferrari) 
    {
        Ferrari B= (Ferrari) A;
        Console.Writeline("This is a Ferrari! specialName is " + B.SpecialName);
    }
    //else if(A is Mercedes)
    //{
            ...
    //}
    else
    {
        Console.Writeline("This is simple car");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what ManageCars is supposed to do - but if it's doing something specific to each derived class, then you should probably have a virtual Manage method on the base Car class and override it in each derived. you can then class A.Manage() inside ManagerCars without worrying about type

Comment: [C# MSDN Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

Comment: this question is a better fit for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you instantiate an object as `Car`, then it will *always* fail the `obj is Ferrari` check. The only reason you can "cast from base to derived" in this case is because the object *is already a Ferrari*, you just accepted the `Car` view of it in the constructor `Ferrari (Car obj )`. You cannot cast something that was constructed as `Car` to `Ferrari`, which sort of makes your question moot.

Comment: I suggest you to read and practice SOLID principles. Specially Liskov substitution.

Answer (score 1):

In your class you should create a virtual function like the following:

```
public virtual void ManageCars()
{
    Console.Writeline("This is simple car");
}
```

All of the derived classes can have derived functionality by overriding the base classes method. For example:

```
public override void ManageCars()
{
    Console.Writeline("This is a Ferrari! specialName is " + B.SpecialName);
}
```

Then for each derived car you can just call ManageCars without any switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using Polymorphism in this case. You will end up with a lot of sub-classes. Create a car class, and add properties such as "Make", "Model", "Color", "Horsepower", etc. Trust me, from experience, that this will save you many headaches in the future.

Having said that, yes you can use the "as" operator to check if a base class is an instance of a sub-class, but it's generally an indicator that the architecture is bad.

Answer (score 1):

When using Polymorphism you generally use casting from the base class to a specialized class when you need to retrieve a special method. For example assuming that you have

```
public class Batmobile: Car 
{
   public void fly() 
   {
     // flying algo here
   }
}
```

Then if you are iterating over a collection of the base type and you need to apply the special behaviour when possible you can cast from the base class to the specialized class and invoque the special behaviour

For example:

```
Car[] cars = new Car[];
// Retrieve your cars collection here
foreach (Car car in cars)
{
   if (car is BatMobile)
   {
      BatMobile batCar = (BatMobile)car;
      batCar.fly();      // No way to invoke this method unless we are sure it's    
                         // a BatMobile

   }
}
```

But in the case presented above it's better to take advantage of the polymorphic abilities of the C# language with virtual method invocation and late binding.

As illustrated by @Jonathan Riger you created a virtual method like ManageCars and then you override it in each special type of descendant. By virtue of polymorphism at runtime the right method will be invoked from the corresponding instance with a compile time call from the base class

**For example**

**in Car class:**

```
public virtual void ManageCars()
{
    Console.Writeline("This is simple car");
}
```

**In Ferrari class:**

```
public override void ManageCars()
{
    Console.Writeline("This is a Ferrari! specialName is " + B.SpecialName);
}
```

**In BatMobile class:**

```
public override void ManageCars()
{
    Console.Writeline("This is a BatMobile car, it can fly really high !");
}
```

**Now assuming we have:**

```
Car[] cars = new Car[3];
cars[0] = new Car();
cars[1] = new Ferrari();
cars[2] = new BatMobile();
```

If you loop over the array and invoke the ManageCar() method like this for example:

```
foreach (Car car in cars) 
{
   car.ManageCars();
}
```

...it will retrieve the right method at runtime even though the compile time invocation is based on the base class which does not know about the specialisation of the method: it's part of the magic of polymorphism :)

Comment: It is very clear, thank you. The case I wanted to describe is the case of the BatMobile which can fly...But If I have  a lot of machine models, each one with a special capability (one can Fly, one Swim etc...) which is the best way to manage the situation?

Comment: @mjfox you leave it to the polymorphic abilities of the language. you override the virtual method for each type and you invoke it in a loop by calling it from the base type and it will work like magic. Try to implement the sample to see how it does it